# Finding a continuous $f\in C(\mathbb{T})$ with $\{\hat{f}(n)\}\notin \ell^p$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, examples-counterexamples, harmonic-analysis

> Denote the circle by $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. Find an example for a continuous function $f\in C(\mathbb{T})$ with coefficients of the fourier series, $\{\hat{f}(n)\}\notin\ell^p,\forall p<2$.

I thought taking a function $f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n f_n$ with $\sum\alpha_n<\infty$ and $\Vert f_n\Vert_\infty \le 1$ which will produce a convergent series on the right side (maybe a power series).

How can I choose my $f=\sum \alpha_n f_n$?

**EDIT:** After Math1000 answered the case $p\in[0,1]$ I still need to figure out the case when $p\in(1,2)$. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sawtooth wave $f(x)=\frac1\pi x$, $x\in(-\pi,\pi]$. The Fourier coefficients are 
\begin{align}
a_0 &= 0\\
a_n &= \frac1\pi \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac1\pi x\sin nx\ \mathsf dx = \frac2{n^2}\sin n\pi -\frac2n\cos n\pi = (-1)^{n+1}\frac2n,n\geqslant 1\\
b_n &= \frac1\pi \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac1\pi x\cos nx\ \mathsf dx =\frac 2n\sin n\pi = 0,\ n\geqslant 1.
\end{align}
So the Fourier series converges, i.e. for $x\in (-\pi,\pi]$, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac2n\sin nx = \frac1\pi x,$$
but the Fourier coefficients $a_n$ are not in $\ell^p$, $0<p\leqslant 1$ as
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^p = 2^p\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{|n|^p}=\infty.$$
To find an example where the coefficients $\hat f(n)$ are not in $l^p$ for a given $1<p<2$ we would need $\hat f(n)\in\Theta((2-p)^n)$. I am not sure if such there exists a such sequence of coefficients that satisfies this condition for all $p\in(0,2)$.

Comment: What about $1<p<2$? which function should I pick then?

Comment: I am not too familiar with Fourier series, so I will defer to someone with more expertise, but I think my answer at least lends some insight (and is definitely too large for a comment).

Comment: thanks. Do you think the limit of Shapiro complex polynomials (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro_polynomials) is fine for $p\in(1,2)$?

Comment: This is not an example, because $f\notin C(\mathbb T).$

Comment: @zhw. I interpreted $f\in C(\mathbb T)$ as piecewise continuity (i.e. continuous on each period) but if the assumption is indeed pointwise continuity then I'm not sure of an example.